# Group the rank and get min and max of the dates

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below table where I have the increasing streak if the activity_date is consecutive. If not, streak will be set to 1.

Now I need to get the min and max of each group of streaks.
Using Spark and scala or Spark SQL.

```
Input

floor   activity_date   streak
--------------------------------
floor1     2018-11-08   1
floor1     2019-01-24   1
floor1     2019-04-05   1
floor1     2019-04-08   1
floor1     2019-04-09   2
floor1     2019-04-14   1
floor1     2019-04-17   1
floor1     2019-04-20   1
floor2     2019-05-04   1
floor2     2019-05-05   2
floor2     2019-06-04   1
floor2     2019-07-28   1
floor2     2019-08-14   1
floor2     2019-08-22   1



Output

floor   activity_date   end_activity_date
----------------------------------------
floor1     2018-11-08      2018-11-08
floor1     2019-01-24      2019-01-24
floor1     2019-04-05      2019-04-05
floor1     2019-04-08      2019-04-09
floor1     2019-04-14      2019-04-14
floor1     2019-04-17      2019-04-17
floor1     2019-04-20      2019-04-20
floor2     2019-05-04      2019-05-05
floor2     2019-06-04      2019-06-04
floor2     2019-07-28      2019-07-28
floor2     2019-08-14      2019-08-14
floor2     2019-08-22      2019-08-22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following approach

### Using Spark SQL

```sql
SELECT
    floor,
    activity_date,
    MAX(activity_date) OVER (PARTITION BY gn,floor) as end_activity_date
FROM (
    SELECT
         *,
         SUM(is_same_streak) OVER (
             PARTITION BY floor ORDER BY activity_date
         ) as gn 
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
             CASE
                 WHEN streak > LAG(streak,1,streak-1) OVER (
                     PARTITION BY floor 
                     ORDER BY activity_date 
                 ) THEN 0
                 ELSE 1
             END as is_same_streak
        FROM
            df
    ) t1
) t2
ORDER BY 
    "floor",
    activity_date
```

[View working demo db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/78CvMJXy7EoyYJRR8z4uvR/0)

### Using scala api

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val floorWindow = Window.partitionBy("floor").orderBy("activity_date")

val output = df.withColumn(
                "is_same_streak",
                when(
                    col("streak") > lag(col("streak"),1,col("streak")-1).over(floorWindow) , 0
                ).otherwise(1)
                
             )
             .withColumn(
                 "gn",
                 sum(col("is_same_streak")).over(floorWindow)
             )
             .select(
                 "floor",
                 "activity_date",
                 max(col("activity_date")).over(
                     Window.partitionBy("gn","floor")
                 ).alias("end_activity_date")
             )
```

### Using pyspark api

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

floorWindow = Window.partitionBy("floor").orderBy("activity_date")

output = (
            df.withColumn(
                "is_same_streak",
                F.when(
                    F.col("streak") > F.lag(F.col("streak"),1,F.col("streak")-1).over(floorWindow) , 0
                ).otherwise(1)
                
             )
             .withColumn(
                 "gn",
                 F.sum(F.col("is_same_streak")).over(floorWindow)
             )
             .select(
                 "floor",
                 "activity_date",
                 F.max(F.col("activity_date")).over(
                     Window.partitionBy("gn","floor")
                 ).alias("end_activity_date")
             )
)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you @ggordon for the answer in all the 3 ways. It did really help.